# Why does copy assignment cause GCC to give a -Wvirtual-move-assign warning?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, virtual-inheritance

The following class hierarchy will cause a [-Wvirtual-move-assign] warning in GCC if a move assign is invoked for an instance of B.

```
struct A {

    std::vector<int> v;

};

struct B : public virtual A {};
```

The following scenarios indeed cause the warning to occur

```
/*** SCENARIO 1 ***/
class C {

    B a;

    public:
        void foo(B& b) {

            b = a; // warning
            // or
            a = b; // warning

        }

};

/*** SCENARIO 2 ***/
void foo(const B& a, B& b) {

    b = a; // warning

}


int main() {

    /*** SCENARIO 3 ***/
    B b;
    std::vector<B> v1;
    v1.push_back(b); // warning

    /*** SCENARIO 4 ***/
    B b1;
    B b2;
    b1 = b2; // warning

    /*** SCENARIO 5 ***/
    B b3;
    b3 = B(); // warning

}
```

The warnings still occur even if the assigned from object is used again later. With the exception of Scenario 5 which involves an rvalue on the right side and therefore would involve a move assignment, I would expect (and indeed I want) a copy assignment to occur rather than a move assignment in these scenarios. If that is the case, then why is this warning occurring? Is a move assignment actually happening somewhere in the expressions?

Comment: "My questions are these" - Please restrict yourself to *one* specific question per Stackoverflow question. Thank you.

Comment: I'd be happy to do that, but the setup for the question would be duplicated in each question. Is that okay?

Comment: IMHO, yes. Each question should be self contained and ask only one specific thing.

Comment: Okay, I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you hit a false positive. The answer to [Why does gcc warn about calling a non-trivial move assignment operator with std::tuple and virtual inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599222/why-does-gcc-warn-about-calling-a-non-trivial-move-assignment-operator-with-std) suggests that gcc emits this warning more often than is really necessary, and that clang does not. So I beefed up your example (as was done in that answer) and gave it to clang.

```
struct A {
    std::vector<int> v;
};

struct AA : public virtual A {};
struct AB : public virtual A {};

struct B : public AA, AB {};
```

With this setup, clang warns only for the `b3 = B();` line (scenario 5). It accepts the other scenarios, suggesting that gcc is just being paranoid. (Either gcc is issuing a false positive or clang has a bug. Your analysis appears correct, though, so probably the former.)